# Why use domain account for SQL Server service?

Tags: sql-server, security, active-directory

I'd like to know the pros and cons of using domain accounts vs using local accounts.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: MS Docs has some good articles about that: [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions) and [Group Managed Service Accounts Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831782(v=ws.11))

Comment: "Give me the pros and cons of {x}" is not really a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested on how to configure accounts for each service in SQL Server, you can find good articles on MS-Docs.

**[Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions)**

> Each service in SQL Server represents a process or a set of processes to manage authentication of SQL Server operations with Windows. This topic describes the **default configuration of services** in this release of SQL Server, and **configuration options for SQL Server services** that you can set during and after SQL Server installation. This topic helps advanced users understand the details of the service accounts.

And let me suggest to have a look at:

**[Group Managed Service Accounts Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831782(v=ws.11))**

> Standalone Managed Service Accounts, which were introduced in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7, **are managed domain accounts that provide automatic password management and simplified SPN management**, including delegation of management to other administrators.

---

> Group Managed Service Accounts **provide a single identity solution for services running on a server farm**, or on systems behind Network Load Balance. By providing a group MSA solution, services can be configured for the new group MSA principal and the password management is handled by Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you are able to manage your environment in a centralised fashion using Active Directory and Group Policy when using Domain Accounts. When you have SQL Server instances running under local accounts unique to each database server, if you wanted to make a change to any security settings across your environment, you would have to do it for the number of instances you have, where if you had a domain account you would only have to make the change **once** (assuming your folders have the correct security settings).

This is the general reason for using domain vs local account, not just for service accounts. There is no way we can list all the benefits here, as some of them are technical and some are business related, and the benefits perceived by a Fortune 500 company with multiple offices and thousands of servers, for example, might be vastly different to those perceived by a small-business running a few instances in a single location.

Hope that answers your question to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

Simply it makes your work Easy, Secure and Principled and especially you sense the advantages when you deal with a lot of servers. I'll write some :

- Create/Copy backup files over network to a backup server easily
- Make the domain account a member of administrators in all of your servers
- Disable logging into the servers for this account from the domain controller
- Easily monitor your servers using third party monitoring tools

and more...

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but also, if you have to access more than one database server from a given database, you can only avoid the "double hop" issue using a Domain Account that has been truste

Comment: this brings nothing new to the gane